# Change the color of the noUiSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, nouislider

I can't really grasp what class should I use to change the color of the slider in [noUiSlider](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/)? I want the slider to have blue color to the left of the slider on the bar, and white to the right; how its demonstrated in [this example](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/#section-Connect). How can I do this?

Here is the part of creation of the slider:

```
$('#slider-range').noUiSlider({
        start: [ start ],
        step: 1,
        range: {
            'min': [ 1 ],
            'max': [ 10 ]
        }
    });
```

and in `html`:

```
<div id="slider-range" type="range"/></div>
```

I tried all possible classes described [here](http://refreshless.com/nouislider/more/#section-styling), but the most I got was to have all bar blue or white, but not blue to the left and white ti the right. So, my question is how can I get this styling?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post your code.

Comment: Please show your css.

Comment: You can find css of noUiSlider [here](https://github.com/leongersen/noUiSlider/blob/master/src/jquery.nouislider.css)

Comment: I don't understand why this question received so many minuses, if it is still not answered. Is it so trivial?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out you have to include `connect` option to slider.

```
$('#slider-range').noUiSlider({
        start: [ start ],
        step: 1,
        connect: "lower",
        range: {
            'min': [ 1 ],
            'max': [ 10 ]
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm using [Materialize Css](https://materializecss.com/range.html) version ***1.0.0*** and it includes noUiSlider as part of the library.

I was trying to style up this control with my own colors and here it is what I got after changing some classes:

[image]

All you have to do is to override this classes:

```css
.noUi-connect {
    background: purple;
}
.noUi-horizontal .noUi-handle, .noUi-vertical .noUi-handle {
    background: purple;
}
.noUi-target.noUi-horizontal .noUi-tooltip {
    background-color: purple;
}
```

Here it is [my pen](https://codepen.io/alexventura/pen/pwZJMK) for reference.
I hope it helps some how.